# Can't set TextBox value from other class despite having created an object of Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set the TextBox value from another class, though can't access the textBox from different classes. So I created an object of Form1 with a method to set the TextBox value, yet it still doesn't set it. I get no error messages.

**Form1 Class:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string text;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text = richTextBox1.Text.ToLower();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalculateVowels cal = new CalculateVowels(text);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void SetText (string text)
    {
        textBox1.Text = text;          //This doesn't work
    }
}
```

**CalculateVowels Class:**

```
class CalculateVowels
{
    public CalculateVowels(string text)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int l = text.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == 'a' || text[i] == 'e' || text[i] == 'i' || text[i] == 'o' || text[i] == 'u')
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        outings(counter);
    }

    public void outings(int vowels)
    {
        string a = vowels.ToString();
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.SetText(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating and setting *different* instance of the form from the one you clicked the button on. You would have to set the text of the *same* instance of the form.

You would have to do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculateVowels cal = new CalculateVowels(this, text);
}

class CalculateVowels
{
    public CalculateVowels(Form1 f, string text)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int l = text.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (text[i] == 'a' || text[i] == 'e' || text[i] == 'i' || text[i] == 'o' || text[i] == 'u')
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        outings(f, counter);
    }

    public void outings(Form1 f, int vowels)
    {
        string a = vowels.ToString();
        f.SetText(a);
    }
}
```

That said, I believe I would not do this work in the constructor of CalculateVowels. Instead, I would create a static method of CalculateVowels, and do the work there:

```
public static void DoCalculation(Form1 f, string text) {...}
```

Comment: Ah, I'm kind of a newbie as you can tell. Is there any way of setting the textBox value from CalculateVowels class?

Comment: That's what I just showed you. You have to pass the form to set as a parameter.

Comment: yes Using the code above, you can set or get the textbox.Text  as follows: f.Textbox.text="anythings" ; ;string var =f.textbox.text

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the already open form instance. You can either pass the form instance like the [answer from John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21171338/961113) or you can access the open forms through [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. Like:

```
public void outings(int vowels)
{
    string a = vowels.ToString();
    var form1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (form1 != null) // form already open
    {
        form1.SetText(a);
    }  
}
```